# Set a hidden buffer as 'nobuflisted'

Tags: vim

How may I set a hidden buffer as 'nolisted' from a vim script?
I tried:
    `call setbufvar(2, 'buflisted', 1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add ampersand sign to 'buflisted' to show to Vim that it is the option:

```
call setbufvar(2, '&buflisted', 1)
```

Comment: To set the value of an option, should be like this?  
    setbufvar(2, '&buftype', 'nofile')

Comment: or if the buffer is already opened let &optionname = value; or set optionname=value